# Basic auth Apache with Tomcat

Tags: configuration, tomcat, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, http-basic-authentication

I have the following server setup:

- Apache Tomcat 7 running Atlassian's Jira (`http:// <server-ip>:8081/tickets`)
- Apache 2.4 web server as reverse proxy serving only the jira application at the moment, but there are more to come (`http://<server-ip>/tickets`)

Now, I want to restrict accesss to the whole system (i.e. `http://<server-ip>/*`) by setting up a basic authentication.

This is how the only enabled apache site config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        <Proxy *>
            Require all granted
        </Proxy>

        ProxyRequests           Off
        ProxyPreserveHost       On

        ProxyPass                /tickets       http://localhost:8081/tickets
        ProxyPassReverse         /tickets       http://localhost:8081/tickets

        <Location />
                AllowOverride AuthConfig
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Restricted Content"
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
                Require user myuser
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But with this config I encounter a problem while trying to log in. After entering the login data, the login window pops up asking again for the login. After three attempts a 401 error is returned by the tomcat! application and not apache.

There is no entry in neither apache's access.log nor error.log for this request. Though apache will log requests with wrong credentials.

How can I configure Apache to proxy all `/tickets/*` requests to Tomcat while forcing the client to authenticate when accessing `/*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It made me suspicious that I got a 401 error from the tomcat application. it seems, that apache fowarded the authorization request, though it shouldn't. I had to remove the `"Authorization"` parameter from the request header.

To do this. I enabled `mod_headers` and added `RequestHeader unset "Authorization"` just before the ProxyPass directives.

So my config looks like the following now:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ProxyRequests           Off
        ProxyPreserveHost       On

        RequestHeader unset "Authorization"       

        <Location "/tickets/rest/">
                  Satisfy Any
                  Order allow,deny
                  Allow from all
        </Location>

        <Location />
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Restricted Content"
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
                Require user myuser
        </Location>

        ProxyPass                /tickets       http://localhost:8081/tickets
        ProxyPassReverse         /tickets       http://localhost:8081/tickets

</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT:

Jira uses its own REST-API for the gadgets, so I had to define a Location-Tag for `/tickets/rest` path.

- removed proxy-tag
- added Location-Tag for the jira-rest API

Got ideas to solve the problem from:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/integrating-jira-with-apache-185729645.html
- https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-19352

Comment: This solution didn't really help. Now the login window pops up every time I call an other page in the application.

Comment: edited my solution. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `Require user myuser` by `Require valid-user`

and remove

```
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
```

Comment: It didn't work. Same result.

Comment: The Apache configuration as i sent you is correct i am using it like that with a proxy, the trouble ssems to be in tomcat part, can you check logs there ? By the way to have more logs, you can set `LogLevel debug rewrite:trace8` then you should find in it the line who said you are successfully loged in on Apache